# How many patterns can be stored in a pattern provider?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-applied-energistics

How many patterns can be stored in a ME pattern provider?

Comment: Did you do **any** research before asking the question?

Comment: Yes but there are multiple wikis that treat the subject and i picked the wrong one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the [wiki](http://tekkitlite.wikia.com/wiki/ME_Pattern_Provider):

> The [ME Pattern Provider](http://tekkitlite.wikia.com/wiki/ME_Pattern_Provider) stores up to 54 [ME Encoded Assembler Pattern](http://tekkitlite.wikia.com/wiki/ME_Encoded_Assembler_Pattern)'s inside of it.